# error while trying to load the gem 'activeadmin'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, gem-bundler

After I add a gem in the gemfile (gem 'presto-client', '~>0.4.5'), I do a bundle install and bundle update. My ruby version is -> ruby-2.1.6
While starting a rails application, I am getting the following error -

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806: warning: already initialized constant Net::SMTPSession
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806: warning: previous definition of SMTPSession was here
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687: warning: already initialized constant Net::POP
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687: warning: previous definition of POP was here
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688: warning: already initialized constant Net::POPSession
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688: warning: previous definition of POPSession was here
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689: warning: already initialized constant Net::POP3Session
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689: warning: previous definition of POP3Session was here
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702: warning: already initialized constant Net::APOPSession
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702: warning: previous definition of APOPSession was here
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activeadmin'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /home/user/src/qbol/tapp/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Activeadmin is installed on my system.

```
 bundle show activeadmin
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/activeadmin-0.6.6
```

Following is my gem file -

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.17'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'rabl', '~> 0.8.0'
gem 'yajl-ruby'
gem 'json'
gem "zendesk_api"
gem 'google-api-client'
gem 'ruby-saml'
#gem 'presto-client', '~> 0.4.8'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.0'

gem 'activevalidators', '~> 1.8.1'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'net-ssh', '~> 2.7.0'
gem 'dogapi'
gem 'devise', '~> 1.5.2'
gem 'haml'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'open4'

gem 'tlsmail'

gem 'backgroundrb-rails3', :require => 'backgroundrb'

gem 'jslint_on_rails'

gem 'flash_render'

gem 'dbi', '~> 0.4.5'

gem 'dbd-mysql'

gem 'uuidtools'

gem 'aws-sdk', '1.40.3'

gem 'aws-sdk-resources', '~> 2'

gem 'algorithms'

gem 'ezcrypto'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem "daemons", '~>1.0.10'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.6'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'

gem "switch_user"

gem "stripe", '>= 1.7.4'

gem 'acts_as_paranoid', '~> 0.4.3'

gem 'lhm', '2.2.0'
```

I  have also done a bundle update and bundle install.

I am trying to run all the commands giving [here](http://activeadmin.info/docs/0-installation.html), but I am not able to run even the first step since I am getting the error unable to load activeadmin error there as well.
How do I solve this error?

**EDIT**
On doing a gem list I get - 
activeadmin (0.6.6, 0.6.0, 0.5.1), Irestricted activeadmin to use version 0.6.6 in gem file but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: try this sudo apt-get install activeadmin

Comment: activeadmin is not a package, it's a gem (Error: No package activeadmin available.)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing nodejs, a JavaScript runtime is required for compiling some assets, I would presume that's the issue. 
At least worked for me:

ArchLinux: `pacman -S nodejs`

Ubuntu: `apt-get install nodejs`

Mac: Probably using homebrew

Answer (score 0):

got same error with version 1.0 pre4

```
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre4'
```

I changed it to:

```
gem 'activeadmin'
```

after running bundler again,

```
bundle
```

it installed latest version which worked for me.

```
Fetching activeadmin 1.3.1
Installing activeadmin 1.3.1
```